# Is there mathmatical function/equation available for ArcGIS Network Analyst's Closest Facility Method?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I would like to use this function in other statistical programming, ideally SAS where td = (whatever the function is to calculate total distance from centroid of county to facility). The goal is to leverage other demographic weights in drive time and distance.

Answer (score 1):

use weights with [Make Closest Facility Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004800000008000000) (Network Analyst) Makes a closest facility network analysis layer and sets its analysis properties. A closest facility analysis layer is useful in determining the closest facility or facilities to an incident based on a specified network cost.

Comment: My question goes a bit further, is there an actual equation available?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want the name of the algorithm that is used by ArcGIS. From what I know, it is primarily based on the [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Here is the pseudo-code from Wikipedia :

```
 function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2      for each vertex v in Graph:                                // Initializations
 3          dist[v]  := infinity ;                                  // Unknown distance function from 
 4                                                                 // source to v
 5          previous[v]  := undefined ;                             // Previous node in optimal path
 6      end for                                                    // from source
 7      
 8      dist[source]  := 0 ;                                        // Distance from source to source
 9      Q := the set of all nodes in Graph ;                       // All nodes in the graph are
10                                                                 // unoptimized – thus are in Q
11      while Q is not empty:                                      // The main loop
12          u := vertex in Q with smallest distance in dist[] ;    // Source node in first case
13          remove u from Q ;
14          if dist[u] = infinity:
15              break ;                                            // all remaining vertices are
16          end if                                                 // inaccessible from source
17          
18          for each neighbor v of u:                              // where v has not yet been 
19                                                                 // removed from Q.
20              alt := dist[u] + dist_between(u, v) ;
21              if alt < dist[v]:                                  // Relax (u,v,a)
22                  dist[v]  := alt ;
23                  previous[v]  := u ;
24                  decrease-key v in Q;                           // Reorder v in the Queue
25              end if
26          end for
27      end while
28      return dist;
29  end function
```

Once you have solved the network, finding the closest facility is straightforward. Solving the network is however computationnaly intensive.